# How can I stop the JSON I get (from an MVC Controller) from being displayed on a new page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm hip-deep in an ASP.NET MVC project and have realized that there's something I ought to be doing with AJAX. I'm new at AJAX so I've started with a little test function, but can't even get that to work. Seems like I'm very close though.

On the View I have:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add4", "Configurators", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="number" name="addend" id="addend" />
    <input type="submit" name="add4go" id="add4go" value="Add 4 to it" />
}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#add4go").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Configurators/Add4',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { addend: $("#addend").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data[sum]);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In ConfiguratorsControllers I have this function:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add4( int addend )
{
    int theSum = addend + 4;
    return (Json(new { sum = theSum }));
}
```

**What I want:** I type in, say, 5, then click on "Go", and the 5 is replaced with a 9.

**What I get:** I type in 5, then click on "Go", and the browser takes me to an entirely new page at /configurators/add4, which contains only:

```
{"sum":9}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (Whoop, @Shyju noticed in their answer that I don't have code to update my value – I did have that before posting but I replaced it with a simple `alert()` to simplify and diagnose.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your form posts back to the same URL your ajax function calls and is posting back after you call your ajax code so it's just going to behave like you didn't put any ajax handler there at all.

return 'false' in the click handler so it does not post back or change to type=button or use a standard hyperlink.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add4", "Configurators", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="number" name="addend" id="addend" />
    <input type="submit" name="add4go" id="add4go" value="Add 4 to it" />
}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#add4go").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Configurators/Add4',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { addend: $("#addend").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data[sum]);
                }
            });
          return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect - I went with changing to type="button" since it seemed simpler, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. Otherwise, clicking on the button submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

> the browser takes me to an entirely new page at /configurators/add4,

Because your button is inside a form and when you click it does a form submit which is the normal behavior.

Since you are doing an ajax call to get the data, You need to prevent the default behavior of a form submit. you can use the jquery `preventDefault()` method to do so.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#add4go").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Configurators/Add4',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { addend: $("#addend").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data[sum]);
                $("#addend").val(data.sum); //update the value
            }
        });
    });
});
```